# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выбрать все строки из файла 1, которых нет в файле 2

Tags: регулярные-выражения, grep

Есть файл f1.txt в котором содержатся такие строки:

```
4304:91fe:8d76:49af
5412:11ee:3d46:44bd
2314:72ec:3f54:12da
```

Есть файл f2.txt, в котором содержатся строки такого вида:

```
UID:4304:91fe:8d76:49af|d1
UID:5412:11ee:3d46:44bd|d2
```

Видно, что идентификаторы в файле 2 такие же, как в файле 1.

В итоге мне нужно получить одну строку:

```
2314:72ec:3f54:12da
```

(этой строки нет во втором файле)

Пробовал так:

```
grep -F -v -f f2.txt f1.txt
```

Эта команда выводит все строки и это неправильно

Comment: Пришли только 2 варианта: либо файл 2 привести к виду файла 1 `cat /f2.txt | sed 's/UID://g;s/|d[0-9]//g'` и после сравнивать `grep -vf /f2.txt /f1.txt`, либо использовать цикл `cat /f1.txt | while read line; do [[ $(grep $line /f2.txt) ]] || echo $line ;done`

Comment: Проголосуйте, пожалуйста, за ответ, у вас уже больше 15 очков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
awk -F'|' 'FNR==NR{sub(/^UID:/,"",$1);a[$1];next};!($1 in a)' f2.txt f1.txt
```

С помощью `-F'|'` задаётся разделитель поля, `sub(/^UID:/,"",$1)` удалит `UID:` в начале строк, поэтому для сравнения будет взята только часть строк между `UID:` и `|d1` в `f2.txt`.